# Difference between dir(…) and vars(…).keys() in Python?

Tags: python

Is there a difference between `dir(…)` and `vars(…).keys()` in Python?

(I hope there is a difference, because otherwise this would break the "one way to do it" principle... :)

Comment: To be clear, the principle is "One *Obvious* way to do it", not "*only* one way to do it".

Answer (score 130, accepted):

Python objects usually store their instance variables in a dictionary that belongs to the object (except for slots). [`vars(x)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#vars) returns this dictionary (as does `x.__dict__`). [`dir(x)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#dir), on the other hand, returns a dictionary of `x`'s "attributes, its class's attributes, and recursively the attributes of its class's base classes."

When you access an object's attribute using the dot operator, Python does a lot more than just look up the attribute in that objects dictionary. A common case is when `x` is an instance of class `C` and you call its method `m`:

```
class C:
    def m(self):
        print("m")
    
x = C()
x.m()
```

The method `m` is not stored in `x.__dict__`. It is an attribute of the class `C`.

When you call `x.m()`, Python will begin by looking for `m` in `x.__dict__`, but it won't find it. However, it knows that `x` is an instance of `C`, so it will next look in `C.__dict__`, find it there, and call `m` with `x` as the first argument.

So the difference between `vars(x)` and `dir(x)` is that `dir(x)` does the extra work of looking in `x`'s class (and its [bases](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#class.__bases__)) for attributes that are accessible from it, not just those attributes that are stored in `x`'s own symbol table. In the above example, `vars(x)` returns an empty dictionary, because `x` has no instance variables. However, `dir(x)` returns

```
['__class__', '__delattr__', '__dict__', '__dir__', '__doc__', '__eq__', 
'__format__', '__ge__', '__getattribute__', '__gt__', '__hash__', 
'__init__', '__init_subclass__', '__le__', '__lt__', '__module__', 
'__ne__', '__new__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', 
'__setattr__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__', '__weakref__', 
'm']
```

Comment: I would add that `dir()` also returns slots, whereas `vars()` doesn't.

Comment: Also the output of `dir` can be customized by implementing the `__dir__` magic method: `class A: def __dir__(self): return ['a']` and then you have `dir(A()) == ['a']` while `vars(A()) == {}`.

Comment: Great Answer !  Very clear and important distinctions are called out.

Answer (score 31):

The documentation has this to say about [`dir`](https://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#dir):

> Without arguments, return the list of names in the current local scope. *With an argument, attempt to return a list of valid attributes for that object.*

And this about [`vars`](https://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#vars):

> Without arguments, return a dictionary corresponding to the current local symbol table. *With a module, class or class instance object as argument (or anything else that has a `__dict__` attribute), returns a dictionary corresponding to the object’s symbol table.*

If you don't see the difference, maybe this will show you more (grouped for easier reading):

```
>>> dir(list)
['__add__', '__class__', '__class_getitem__', '__contains__', '__delattr__', 
'__delitem__', '__dir__', '__doc__', '__eq__', '__format__', '__ge__', 
'__getattribute__', '__getitem__', '__gt__', '__hash__', '__iadd__', '__imul__', 
'__init__', '__init_subclass__', '__iter__', '__le__', '__len__', '__lt__', 
'__mul__', '__ne__', '__new__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', 
'__reversed__', '__rmul__', '__setattr__', '__setitem__', '__sizeof__', 
'__str__', '__subclasshook__', 'append', 'clear', 'copy', 'count', 'extend', 
'index', 'insert', 'pop', 'remove', 'reverse', 'sort']
>>> vars(list).keys()
dict_keys(['__repr__', 
'__hash__', 
'__getattribute__', 
'__lt__', '__le__', '__eq__', '__ne__', '__gt__', '__ge__', 
'__iter__', 
'__init__', 
'__len__', 
'__getitem__', '__setitem__', '__delitem__', 
'__add__', '__mul__', '__rmul__', '__contains__', '__iadd__', '__imul__', 
'__new__', 
'__reversed__', '__sizeof__', 
'clear', 'copy', 'append', 'insert', 'extend', 'pop', 'remove', 'index', 'count', 'reverse', 'sort', 
'__class_getitem__', 
'__doc__'])
```

If you don't feel like reading through that, `dir` includes these attributes while `vars` does not:

```
>>> set(dir(list)) - vars(list).keys()
{'__class__', '__delattr__', '__dir__', '__format__', '__init_subclass__', 
'__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__setattr__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__'}
```

Note also that `dir()`'s output is sorted alphabetically, whereas `vars()`'s output is sorted by the order the attributes were defined in.

Comment: I guess that "symbol table" is the key term, here.  It is quite hard to find its definition in the official Python documentation (in fact, I have yet to find it :)).

Answer (score 3):

Apart from Answers given, I would like to add that, using vars() with instances built-in types will give error, as instances builtin types do not have `__dict__` attribute.

eg.

```
In [96]: vars([])
---------------------------------------------------------------------------

TypeError Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-96-a6cdd8d17b23> in <module>()
      ----> 1 vars([])
TypeError: vars() argument must have __dict__ attribute
```

Comment: @SiHa, It's actually the instance of builtin-types, which don't have `__dict__` attribute. Thanks for correcting me. I have updated the answer.

Comment: Good point. Also, instances of custom classes that implement [\_\_slots\_\_](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/472000/usage-of-slots) do not have a \_\_dict\_\_ attribute either and would similarly give an error.