# Why does vars(response) not show response.text? (using Python Requests module)

Tags: python, python-requests

```
import requests
response = requests.get('http://httpbin.org/get')
print vars(response) # no response.text listed
print response.text # value printed
```

Why does `vars(response)` not list `response.text` when that value exists?

`dir(response)` does list `response.text`, but that does not print the value of it.

Comment: @aruisdante the question here is basically about `vars()`,  `text` and other properties that a `Response` class has.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the first question, the reason `text` doesn't show up in `vars` is [because it's a property](https://github.com/kennethreitz/requests/blob/master/requests/models.py#L741) (defined by `@property`) as opposed to a class attribute (which is what ends up in `__dict__` shown by `vars`).

For the second question, this is because the way `dir` and `vars` work.

From the documentation for `vars`:

> vars([object])
>
> Return the **dict** attribute for a module, class, instance, or any
>   other object with a **dict** attribute.
>
> Objects such as modules and instances have an updateable **dict**
>   attribute; however, other objects may have write restrictions on their
>   **dict** attributes (for example, new-style classes use a dictproxy to prevent direct dictionary updates).
>
> Without an argument, vars() acts like locals(). Note, the locals
>   dictionary is only useful for reads since updates to the locals
>   dictionary are ignored.

And for `dir`:

> The default dir() mechanism behaves differently with different types
>   of objects, as it attempts to produce the most relevant, rather than
>   complete, information:
>
> If the object is a module object, the list contains the names of the
>   module’s attributes. If the object is a type or class object, the list
>   contains the names of its attributes, and recursively of the
>   attributes of its bases. Otherwise, the list contains the object’s
>   attributes’ names, the names of its class’s attributes, and
>   recursively of the attributes of its class’s base classes.

So basically `dir` just prints out the attributes of the passed in argument, *not* its corresponding value.

Also, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/981624/193906) is pretty comprehensive in explaining the differences.

Comment: Ah, thank you, you explained the key: `text` is a class property as opposed to a class attribute. And looking into the source code, it is because `text` is not just a simple variable, it is a property that does some additional logic.

Answer (score 1):

It is not in the `vars` results because `vars` does not resolve attributes to the parent class of an object.  See [this other thread on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/980249/difference-between-dir-and-vars-keys-in-python).

You can request all "attributes, its class's attributes, and recursively the attributes of its class's base classes" by using `dir` on the object:

```
In [1]: import requests

In [2]: response = requests.get('http://httpbin.org/get')

In [3]: 'text' in vars(response)
Out[3]: False

In [4]: 'text' in dir(response)
Out[4]: True
```

Comment: OK, so that is the technical reason. But why would `response.text` be an attribute whereas `response.status_code` is not an attribute? They seem like they should be in the same category.

Comment: @wisbucky that question is for the designers of requests.  What one can gather from the source code [here](https://github.com/kennethreitz/requests/blob/bd3cf95e34aa49c8d764c899672048df107e0d70/requests/models.py#L520) is that `status_code` is an instance variable because it is initialized in the constructor `__init__`, while `text` is a class `@property`.  Probably this is because constructing the text requires more logic than just evaluating a value ...