# Making a JSON model in python

Tags: python, json

I'm usually used to Laravel PHP where I am able to do things such as **Auth::User()->name** however I need to make a game in Python for my class.
I would like to be able to do **Colours.black** or something similar however I am struggling.

I have a Python file called **Colours.py** and it looks something like this:

```
import json


class Colours(object):

    def __init__(self):
        with open('app/colours.json') as data:
                self.__dict__ = json.loads(data)
```

My JSON file looks like this:

```
[
  {
    "black": "(0, 0, 0)",
    "white": "(255, 255, 255)",
    "green": "(0, 255, 0)"
  }
]
```

And then in another Python file called **Main.py** I have the following:

```
from app.models import Colours

print(dir(Colours))
```

This code does not work.

Edit: 
Sorry forgot to give the output:

```
['Colours', '__builtins__', '__cached__', '__doc__', '__file__', '__loader__', '__name__', '__package__', '__spec__', 'json']
```

Edit 2:
I am able to do:

```
print(Colours.Colours().black)
## Output: (0, 0, 0)
```

However I was wondering whethere this is a way to do Just **Colours.black**?

Comment: Try to have more focused questions. What is the output you are expecting. What about this code doesn't satisfy your needs?

Comment: Try using `json.load(data)[0]` to extract the dictionary from the outer list.  This will initialize your `__dict__` variable with the key-value pairs from the JSON.  (Note: the JSON contains a list of length one, where the single element is the dictionary you want)

Comment: @AbbeGijly Still doesn't seem to work :(

Comment: @Filip Is that better? ^^

Comment: Also replace `json.loads` with `json.load`.  `.load()` takes a file handle; `.loads()` takes a string

Comment: @Ethan yeah that's better but are you sure you didn't delete any of the output? Why isn't the `__init__` method displayed?

Comment: I think you are printing the file and not the class. `Colours` is the file you imported and it can't show you the `__init__` method inside your class. Try `print(dir(Colours.Colours))`

Comment: @Filip This just prints `['__class__', '__delattr__', '__dict__', '__dir__', '__doc__', '__eq__', '__format__', '__ge__', '__getattribute__', '__gt__', '__hash__', '__init__', '__init_subclass__', '__le__', '__lt__', '__module__', '__ne__', '__new__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__setattr__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__', '__weakref__']
`

Comment: @Ethan yeah try printing the `__dict__` method, I just helped you go to your class, because you were printing the available file magic methods

Comment: To print the instance's variables you should use `vars()` method instead of `dir()`. To know more about their differences: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/980249/difference-between-dir-and-vars-keys-in-python

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can solve it by creating the class as type with static variables so you won't need to initialize the class

**Colours.py**:

```
import json

with open('app/colours.json') as data:
   Colours = type("Colours", (), json.load(data)[0])
```

Comment: Thank you!
I had to modify your solution to look like this:
`with open('app/colours.json') as data: colour = type("Colours", (), json.load(data))` So it made more sense grammatically.

Answer (score 0):

You are viewing the file's magic methods and not the class'.

First you need to import your `Colours.py` file and then run the `__init__` method of your `Colours` class. Try creating an object to do that:

```py
from app.models import Colours

obj = Colours.Colours()
print(obj.__dict__)
```

**Colours.py**

```py
import json

class Colours(object):
    def __init__(self):
        with open("app/colours.json") as data:
            self.__dict__ = json.load(data)[0]
```

This code will print the dictionary in your `__dict__` method.

To explain what is happening here. First you are importing your `Colours.py` file inside the `app/models/` directories. Inside that file you have created a `Colours` class that you need to run it's `__init__` magic method that will set the `__dict__` method to the dictionary from you json file. So first you need to run that **init** method by running that class by creating an object from it. Then you just access that method and you print that dictionary.